# Display not working even after trying new graphics card

Tags: display, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

I am having some odd issues with my brothers computer. There were issues with the screen not getting any input, but the computer would be starting up fine, no beeps or anything. I attempted using different screens and cables and still was no signal. The computer did used to work fine, just one day after waking from sleep mode stopped sending a signal.

I tried replacing the CMOS battery and this did not fix the issue. Using the Intel HD graphics through the motherboard work (VGA plugged into MB instead of Graphics card). However plugging into the graphics card it does not work. The odd thing is that if you fiddle around swapping the ports and turning it on and off eventually after many attempts there will be input again when plugged in via the Graphics card. And it all works fine... until a reboot or waking from sleep mode, in which case there is no signal again.

I have also tried totally replacing the graphics card with a brand new one, still the **exact** same issue as before.

I am unclear at this point what I can still test to figure out the problem. I have tested cables, screens, cmos battery, resetting cmos, reflashing cmos/bios, and even replacing the graphics card.

What else could be tested here?

Comment: What is the motherboard and graphics card make/model? It could be a physical issue with the PCIe slot on the board, or if the GPU needs PCIe power from the PSU, maybe that connector is faulty?

Comment: @Ash no additional power is required via a separate cable, it all goes through the PCIe slot. The motherboard is an [H81M-E](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/H81ME/). The old card was a [Club Radeon R7 240](http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/radeon-r7-240.html) and the card I replaced it with as a test is a [Asus Radeon R7 240](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Graphics_Cards/R72402GD3L/)

Comment: Hmm...when the problem occurs, do you see that BIOS/motherboard splash on reboot, or nothing at all? What is the power supply, and do you have a spare you could try? Have you tried unplugging everything but the bare minimum (a faulty drive, for example, can sometimes cause the weirdest things to happen).

Comment: @Ash Yes unplugging has been tried. No splash screen. But like I said in my post connecting to the MB instead of GFX card works. Power supply should not be an issus as there are rare cases as mentioned where the GFX card will give an output and there never was a problem before. It was always fine for the year before.

Comment: Only reason I asked about PSU is some don't officially support the sleep state requirements for Haswell CPUs. But as you say if it's a new problem, and you rule out everything else, I guess it leaves the motherboard as the most likely cause. Hardest part to test though unfortunately :/

Comment: @Ash and the computer's build was designed and put together by the place it was bought from so the parts should all be properly compatible. Is there anyway to test the PCIe slot?